# Why we are checking my last row/column? Conway Game of LIfe

Tags: java, conways-game-of-life

I have problem at Conway Game of Life. To avoid an index out of bounds I started the loop at [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alWNX.png) and limited the back boundary with field.length-1.
However, the last column and row is not output for me and I don't know why.
I know that there are several solutions available on the Internet. Unfortunately these did not help me directly. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
for(int i=1; i<feld.length-1;i++)
            {
                int zählvariable=0;
                for(int j=1; j<feld.length-1;j++)
                {
                    for(int l=-1;l<=1;l++)
                    {
                        for(int m=-1;m<=1;m++)
                        {   
                                    if(feld[i+l][j+m]=='+')
                                    {
                                        zählvariable++;
                                    }
                            
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                    if ((feld[i][j]=='+') && (zählvariable<2))
                    {
                        neuesFeld[i][j] = '-';
                    }
                    else if((feld[i][j]=='+') && (zählvariable>3))
                    {
                        neuesFeld[i][j] = '-';
                    }
                    else if((feld[i][j]=='-') && (zählvariable==3))
                    {
                        neuesFeld[i][j] = '+';
                    }
                    else
                        neuesFeld[i][j]=feld[i][j];

                    zählvariable=0;
```

Solution:

[image]

Comment: You don't have this problem on the left or top because you begin i,j at 1 instead of 0. The easiest solution would be to increase your array size so you can safely access feld[i+l][j+m] at the maximum values.

Comment: OK but i would like to play the Game of Life with many Generations. So i have to increase my Array for every gen. Or?